# Multiple AND conditions MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How can I have multiple AND conditions in a clause?  Like `SELECT * FROM database WHERE x=x,y=y AND z=z` I tried that, and it didn't work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE x=x AND y=y AND z=z
```

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE `x`=x AND `y`=y AND `z`=z
```